# GWT surrounding elements with href

Tags: java, gwt, click, href

Is there some clean solution (or clean workaround) to surround more elements with href. 
eg.
I have something like this

```
VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
Label l1 = new Label("This is label 1");
Label l2 = new Label("This is label 2");
vp.add(l1);
vp.add(l2);
```

I would like to make href from this construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

way 1. Use HTMLPanel with outer < A > element:

```
hp = new HTMLPanel("<a href=... id="myid"></a>");
hp.add(vp, "myid");
```

way 2. Install clickHandlers on all label elements:

```
ch = new ClickHanler() {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event)  {
     Window.open(...);
  }
};
l1.addClickHandler(ch);
l2.addClickHandler(ch);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There were problem with click handler, it was newer executed, so I made small correction:

Answer (score 2):

A clean(er) solution would be, IMHO, using [`FocusPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html). You can add a `ClickHandler` to the whole panel - the result is that whatever you click on in that panel will get handled by that one `ClickHandler` (no need to add the `ClickHandler` to all the `Widgets` inside):

```
VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
Label l1 = new Label("This is label 1");
Label l2 = new Label("This is label 2");
vp.add(l1);
vp.add(l2);

FocusPanel focusPanel = new FocusPanel();
focusPanel.add(vp);
ClickHandler clickHandler = new ClickHanler() {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event)  {
     Window.open(...);
  }
};
focusPanel.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
```

Please note that `FocusPanel` is a [`SimplePanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimplePanel.html) - meaning it can hold only one `Widget`, most likely another `Panel`, like `VerticalPanel` in this case. 
`FocusPanel` implements a lot of other Handlers, so make sure to check them all out - they tend to be very useful in other use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class HrefVerticalPanel where you override the add method to surround the added element with an Anchor object

```
class HrefVerticalPanel extends VerticalPanel {
  public void add(Widget w) {
    Anchor surrounding = new Anchor();
    surrounding.add(w);
    super.add(surrounding);
    handleAnchorUrl(surrounding);
  } 

  protected void handleAnchorUrl(Anchor toBeClicked) {...}
}
```